# setHours and setMinutes is not working React class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, react-class-based-component

I am getting the time output is disabled. Please take a look at the image attached. I have imported `setHours` and `setMinutes` library [image]

```
  state = {
    startTime: new Date(),
    time: null 
  };
  handleChange = time => {
    this.setState({
      startTime: time,
    });   
  };
render() {
      return (
        <div className="dateandtime-picker-box">
        <DatePicker
          autoFocus={false}
          placeholderText="Time"
          className="react-datepicker-wrapper"
          selected={this.state.startTime}
          onChange={time => this.handleChange(time)}
          maxTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 17)}
          minTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 7)}
          isClearable
          showTimeSelect
          showTimeSelectOnly
          timeIntervals={30}
          timeCaption="Time"
          dateFormat="h:mm aa"
        >
        </DatePicker>
        </div>
      )
}
```

Comment: Probably because those time fall out of maxTime and minTime

Comment: I checked . it didnt work.